# Combining length of arrays, why is it returning NaN? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Info:**   Hi you can see there are 4 arrays, and then an array with those arrays inside.  I'm using _.reduce to add up the length of the arrays.  I'm getting NaN when I call the function with the array of arrays.  I would expect to get 19.

Why is this?  Thanks for help

```
var array1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];
var array2 = ["a", "b"];
var array3 = [{name : "John"}, {age : 21}];
var array4 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

var array5 = [array4, array3, array2, array1];

var arrayComboLength = function(array){
return _.reduce(array, function(a,b){
    return a.length + b.length;
});
}


console.log(arrayComboLength(array5));  --> // NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `reduce`'s callback is the accumulator. You are accessing the `length` of a number and that results in `undefined`. And then you are adding `undefined` to the numbers that are the lengths of the rest of the arrays which results in `undefined`.

```
var arrayComboLength = function(array) {
  return _.reduce(array, function(a, b) {
    return a + b.length;
  }, 0);
}
```

This is very close to the example given in the documentation http://underscorejs.org/#reduce

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, that works.  In your solution there if I don't include that 0, I get this as the result  -->  // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0225

Not sure why I get that.  I was under the impression if we leave out the starting value (the 0) it will start from anyway.

Comment: *Correction*  I was under the impression if we leave out the starting value (the 0) it will start from 0 anyway.   Is that not true?

Comment: @AugustusBrennan No, it uses the first array element if you do not specify otherwise, and starts running on the second element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

The counting function will be recursively applied to all elements of the array. Recursively, so they will also be applied to the scalar values in array4, for example. Scalar values don't have a length.